# Unabe to update current row data with the one in previous row

Tags: sql, partition, rownum

Can anyone help me in the below execution :

I want to update RACF_ID and SUPV_RACF columns of date_value 8-JAN-2018 with the data in RAC_ID and SUPV_RACF columns of date_value 01-JAN-2018. Basically I want to update the data of a particular date value to the data present in the date_value of a week before.(date_value - 7).It should only update the rows with column effective_dt as null.

Below is the query which I tried but failed to get output :
declare
cursor C1 is

```
select * from temp_join;
begin
for i in C1
Loop
update temp_join r 
set r.RACF_ID = i.RACF_ID ,
r.SUPV_RACF = i.SUPV_RACF   
where  to_date(r.date_value , 'dd-mon-yyyy') = to_date(i.date_value , 'dd-mon-yyyy') -7 and
to_date(r.date_value , 'dd-mon-yyyy') > to_date('01-JAN-2018' , 'dd-mon-yyyy') and R.Effective_Dt is null ;
end Loop;
end;
```

Below images will show :

**Current scenario of the table**

[image: Current scenario of the table]

**Desired output**

[image: Desired output]

I tried self join also :

```
update temp_join r
   set (r.racf_id, r.supv_racf) =
          (select i.racf_id, i.supv_racf i
             from temp_join i
            where    i.racf_id = r.racf_id                       --> remark A
                  and to_date(r.date_value , 'dd-mon-yyyy') = to_date(i.date_value , 'dd-mon-yyyy') -7
                  )  --> remark B
 where     to_date(r.date_value , 'dd-mon-yyyy') > to_date('01-JAN-2018' , 'dd-mon-yyyy')
 and to_date(r.date_value , 'dd-mon-yyyy') < to_date('05-MAR-2018' , 'dd-mon-yyyy')
       and r.effective_dt is null;
```

But the above query also doesnt seem to give the desired output